# Getting only last line of continuous stdout

Tags: stdout, sar

I'm using **sar** to collect network statistics from my **wlp2s0** interface (1 second interval), like so:

```
$ sar -n DEV 1 | grep wlp2s0
```

and the continuous output looks like this:

```
18:15:06       wlp2s0      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
18:15:07       wlp2s0      1,00      2,00      0,12      0,28      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
18:15:08       wlp2s0      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
18:15:09       wlp2s0      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
18:15:10       wlp2s0      0,00      1,00      0,00      0,24      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
18:15:11       wlp2s0      0,00      1,00      0,00      0,24      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
```

I want to write only the last line of the output (the current measurement) in a .txt file. The thing is, I don't know how to construct a command to do this.

The only way I can write to a file (which is continuously increasing its size, and that's not what I want) is by doing:

```
$ sar -n DEV 1 > output.txt
```

The stdout is always increasing and because I'm overwriting the file, all previous and upcoming lines will be written.

[EDIT] My problem is not dependent on this tool (sar), it happened with any tool with continuous output. I've heard of circular buffers, but I don't think it would work in this case.

Comment: A few lines of python would do the trick. Got a friend who's a coder?

Comment: Actually I've tried to do it in Python, even with circular buffers. But it still does not work the way I want. Maybe I must learn a bit more of python. Guess that for now I'll stick with the shell script solution.

Comment: The python version would resemble the Perl version in another comment, anyway. It's just the language that I think in these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done from within the shell, by looping over the output lines, and writing each line to your desired output file, like this:

```
sar -n DEV 1 |
grep wlp2s0  |
while read ln
do
  printf '%s\n' "$ln" > output.txt
done
```

@OleTange's `perl`-based solution might be more efficient in terms of process creation, but if your shell happens to have a built-in `printf` this method could be almost as lean.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you please explain where I should place the "grep wlp2s0" in that piece of code? Because the requirement is not only to be the most recent line, it must also contain the "wlp2s0" string

Comment: My apologies for overlooking the `grep` usage.  I've edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sar -n DEV 1 |
  perl -ne 'if(/wlp/) { open(O,">current"); print O; close O }'
```

Comment: Or awk opens implicitly `|awk '/wlp/{print>"current";close("current")}'`